# how to add flags to a grunt execute task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

i am trying to run a node file with grunt.js

for some reasons i am not able to provide the node file with argument.

this is what i want to happend:

```
node server/index.js -e development-local
```

and this is my  configuration:

```
   execute: {
      development_target: {
        src: ['index.js'],
        options: {
          args: ['e development-local',]
        }
      }
    }

  grunt.registerTask('serve-local', ['execute:development_target']);
```

but it is not working for some reason. i tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using [grunt-execute](https://github.com/Bartvds/grunt-execute#options) for this task.

From the library your args options must be an array to display your argument.

Have you tried :

```
execute: {
  development_target: {
    src: ['index.js'],
    options: {
      args: ['-e', 'development-local']
    }
  }
}

grunt.registerTask('serve-local', ['execute:development_target']);
```

Plus `src: ['index.js']` seems to be the path of your file. Have you tried `src: ['server/index.js']` ?

Do you have any error print in your console ?